# Will iphone 5 run a binary submitted with only ARMv7 (and not ARMv7s)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

Just wondering if I inlcude ARMv7 only and exclude ARMv7s in my binary if it will still actually run on an iPhone 5?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the two are backwards compatible. Been asked many times before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just think of all the existing apps on the App Store that have only ever been compiled for ARMv7, they all work on the iPhone 5.

Comment: How about iPhone 5s using armv64. Will it be able to run armv7 only builds? I assume yes, but better be sorry than safe.